# ¿Se puede ejecutan un .SQL con muchos LOAD FILE en PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo un fichero .SQL que internamente tiene muchos LOAD FILE, cada LOAD FILE apunta a un fichero diferente.

Actualmente, cargo el fichero .SQL y lo corro línea por línea, sin embargo, me gustaría preguntar si existe la posibilidad de acelerar el proceso de carga.

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente:

```
function ejecutarSQL($pdo)
{
    $q = explode(';', file_get_contents('mi_fichero.sql'));
    foreach($q as $query)
    {
        if($query != '')
        {
            echo "Ejecutando.. ".$query."\n";
            $pdo->query($query);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dos cosas mejoran ese procedimiento utiliza "beginTransaction" y lo otro es preparar el query "$pdo->prepare($query);" antes de la ejecución.

Aquí el código:

```php
function ejecutarSQL($pdo)
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $q = explode(';', file_get_contents('mi_fichero.sql'));
    foreach($q as $query)
    {
        if($query != '')
        {
            echo "Ejecutando.. ".$query."\n";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $pdo->commit();
}
```

Comment: Tiene buena pinta!! lo voy a probar y acepto tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las sentencias preparadas no siempre es lo mejor en términos de desempeño, requieren recursos adicionales cuyo consumo se justifica al ejecutar varias veces una **misma sentencia**. ¿Será éste el caso?. Por otro lado ¿cabrá en la memoria el contenido completo del fichero?.

Comment: Una transacción retiene recursos mientras no se confirme, en este caso, durante todo el proceso del fichero. Es decir, propones un cóctel que en éste caso en particular podría (hasta el momento no hemos visto un ejemplo del fichero) ser totalmente contraproducente.

Comment: @Carlos avisa como te fue.

Comment: De momento estoy teniendo muchos problemas, porque algo que no aclaré es que los "LOAD FILE" incluyen "SET @var = nullif(@var, '')" y las comillas simples me provocan error. Estoy dudando mucho con esto. He modificado tu condición "if($query != '')" para añadir más casos (espacios, etc). Si me puedes ayudar con lo que te comento, te lo agradecería. Cuando logre hacer la carga, te comento.

Comment: Hola, @Sal y Alberto, veamos... esto se me ha complicado un poco. La cuestión aquí es que tengo ficheros que pesan alrededor de 2.9 GB, otros 2.3 GB, etc ¿Es posible cargarlos haciendo LOAD DATA FILE o existe un límite máximo por fichero?

Comment: Mi idea era concatenar todos los ficheros, es decir, tener un fichero por tabla pero el peso aumentaba consideramente en algunos de ellos. El máximo pesaba 40GB y creo que no es posible cargar eso con LOAD DATA FILE de MySQL. Así que lo que tengo es un .sql por tabla y dentro de ese fichero tengo N sentencias SQL, cada sentencia SQL es un LOAD DATA FILE que apunta a un CSV diferente pero que es parte de esa tabla. El problema es que hay CSV que pesan más de 1 GB. En fin, ¿cuál sería la forma más eficiente?